# Jquery UI Widget Problem - Rounded Corners

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, html, widget

http://jsbin.com/adojes/edit#preview

my problem is to set the "rounded-corners" from jquery ui to the main container without setting a total high for it - is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a line break with `clear: both` after the sidebar. Example: http://jsbin.com/adojes/2/edit#preview

```
<div id="main" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <div class="content ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        Sidebar<br />Sidebar<br />Sidebar<br />
    </div>
    <br style='clear: both'/>
</div>
```